# JAX-RS/Jersey 2 file download - Is there a common API for server and generated client proxy

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I autogenerate the JAX-RS interfaces from Swagger.
I use Jersey 2.25.1.

All works fine for most of the use cases. We have the same interface for the server and client parts.
Clients are generated from the interface with `org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory`.

Now I need to implement file download via streaming (files gonna be huge, typically in the gigabyte range, so streaming is required).

I can use the following signature for the server:

```
@GET
@Path("/DownloadFile")
@Produces({"application/octet-stream"})
StreamingOutput downloadFileUniqueId();
```

But `StreamingOutput` cannot obviously be used in the client.

Is there any feature in JAX-RS / Jersey to have a common interface between server and client ?

I've seen for the upload, this is possible using `FormDataMultiPart`, I'd like a similar solution for download...

Comment: In the client code, you have to read response entity as input stream - `InputStream responseStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);` and then read this stream for getting actual file content.

Comment: Try using a Response return type, and then in the client code, you can call `response.get(InputStream.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found a working solution using a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object as return type:

Server code:

```
public Response downloadFile(String uniqueId){
    InputStream inputStream = filePersistenceService.read(uniqueId);
    Response.ok(outputStream -> IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)).build()
```

}

Client code:

```
Response response = client.downloadFile(uniqueId);
InputStream resultInputStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```

This works fine with clients generated by `org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory`.